# If statement executed even if the condition is false

Tags: java

I have a method that generate random number but i want some of them to be trashed. 
This is the code:

```
    public static int getRandomX(int max, int[] exclude){
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        Integer[] toExclude = Arrays.stream( exclude ).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
        Integer random = Integer.valueOf(randomGenerator.nextInt(max));
        do{
            System.out.println(!Arrays.asList(toExclude).contains(random));
            if(!(Arrays.asList(toExclude).contains(random))){
                return random;
            } else{
                random ++;
            }
        }while(!Arrays.asList(toExclude).contains(random));
        return random;
    }
```

Even if the `System.out.println(!Arrays.asList(toExclude).contains(random));` print false the if get executed and i get a wrong random number

Comment: The loop stops if the random must be excluded, and immediately after the loop, you return the random. Your loop condition is incorrect.

Comment: Try putting `System.out.println("Was true");` in the `if` branch and `System.out.println("Was false");` in the `else` branch. Otherwise you have not really shown that the `if` branch gets executed. If you ever see `false` followed immediately by `Was true`, then there is a serious problem with the universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather work with sets than lists. The advantage is you can add an element to a set and depending on whether the element already exists or not `set.add` returns true or false, making your while loop easier and more readable:

```
public static int getRandomX(int max, int[] exclude){
    Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(exclude).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Random randomGenerator = new Random(max);
    Integer random = randomGenerator.nextInt(max);
    while(!set.add(random)){
        random = randomGenerator.nextInt(max);
    }
    return random;
}
```

But be careful! Both this approach and that of `@Nicholas K`  ends in an endless loop if exclude contains all numbers between 0 and max-1. To prevent this, add a validation of the arguments as given below. There is also another advantage of sets over lists since you don't have to filter duplicates first.

```
public static int getRandomX(int max, int[] exclude){
    Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(exclude).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    if(set.size() == max){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("All numbers in range [0 - " +(max-1)+"] excluded");
        //or return -1;
    }
    Random randomGenerator = new Random(max);
    Integer random = randomGenerator.nextInt(max);
    while(!set.add(random)){
        random = randomGenerator.nextInt(max);
    }
    return random;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an incorrect logic in the while loop. You need to execute the loop as long as there is a number that needs to be excluded and not the other way around.

Simply your code to:

```
public static int getRandomX(int max, int[] exclude) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    Integer[] toExclude = Arrays.stream(exclude).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    Integer random;
    do {
        random = Integer.valueOf(randomGenerator.nextInt(max));
    } while (Arrays.asList(toExclude).contains(random));
    return random;
}
```

Comment: Not my downvote. But note that this can end in an endless loop if `exclude`  contains all numbers between `0 and max-1`.